# How to get the indexes of rows which has values of x number of features same while differing one feature?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Sample DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Peter','John','John','Donald'],
              'City':['Boston','Japan','Boston','Dallas','Japan'],
              'Age':[23,31,21,21,22]})
```

[image: dataframe]

What i want is to get list of indices of all the rows which has same 'Name' and 'City' but different age, using pandas. 
In this case : it should return [0,2]

Comment: What should happen when there is a 6th row `John Boston 23`? Do you want indices 0,2 and 5 then?

Comment: Okay...i hate to break it now, but i'm removing all the duplicates(all values including Age) beforehand. So, the above case would'nt happen at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this below:

```
df[df.duplicated(['Name','City'],keep=False)&~df.duplicated(keep=False)]

   Name    City  Age
0  John  Boston   23
2  John  Boston   21
```

EDIT: The scenario that @ALollz had pointed out can be acheived using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Peter','John','John','Donald', 'John'],
              'City':['Boston','Japan','Boston','Dallas','Japan', 'Boston'],
              'Age':[23,31,21,21,22, 23]})
df[df.duplicated(['Name','City'],keep=False)].drop_duplicates()
```

**Output:**

```
   Name    City  Age
0  John  Boston   23
2  John  Boston   21
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want is to get list of indices of all the rows which has same 'Name' and 'City' but different age

I think this is a bit ambiguous, because what if a Name-City group has a combination of entries with the same age and some that differ? Depending upon your desired output `groupby` + `transform` + `nunique` to filter may be required.

#### Sample Data:

Note, the edge case I added here, where `John  Boston   23` is duplicated:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Peter','John','John','Donald', 'John'],
                  'City':['Boston','Japan','Boston','Dallas','Japan', 'Boston'],
                  'Age':[23,31,21,21,22, 23]})

#     Name    City  Age
#0    John  Boston   23
#1   Peter   Japan   31
#2    John  Boston   21
#3    John  Dallas   21
#4  Donald   Japan   22
#5    John  Boston   23
```

#### Code:

```
df[df.groupby(['Name', 'City']).Age.transform(pd.Series.nunique).gt(1)]

#   Name    City  Age
#0  John  Boston   23
#2  John  Boston   21
#5  John  Boston   23
```

---

With other solutions, the exact duplication may lead to an unwanted output:

```
df[df.duplicated(['Name','City'],keep=False)&~df.duplicated(keep=False)]
#   Name    City  Age
#2  John  Boston   21
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method could be by using groupby():

```
df[df.groupby(['Name', 'City']).transform(len)['Age']>1]
```

or may be in two steps as using duplicated():

```
df =df.set_index('Age')
df[df.duplicated(['Name', 'City'], keep = False)].reset_index()
```

Comment: this doesn't give the desired results. also, i'm skeptical on how the groupby would fare on >~300 columns